# Chef: why can't I subscribe to a directory :create action?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, provisioning, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have created the following recipe block which should run at the point that the `/etc/httpd/ssl` directory is created:

```rb
ruby_block "Copy SSL certificates" do
  block do
    certificate_file = "#{node['magento']['apache']['project_ssl_location']}/#{node['magento']['apache']['ssl_certificate_filename']}"
    key_file = "#{node['magento']['apache']['project_ssl_location']}/#{node['magento']['apache']['ssl_certificate_key_filename']}"
    chain_file = "#{node['magento']['apache']['project_ssl_location']}/#{node['magento']['apache']['ssl_certificate_chain_filename']}"

    if File.exists?(certificate_file) && File.exists?(key_file)
      FileUtils.cp(certificate_file, "#{node['apache']['dir']}/ssl")
      FileUtils.cp(key_file, "#{node['apache']['dir']}/ssl")
    end

    if File.exists?(chain_file)
      FileUtils.cp(chain_file, "#{node['apache']['dir']}/ssl")
    end
  end
  action :nothing
  subscribes :create, resources(:directory => "/etc/httpd/ssl")
end
```

(This is directly modelled off an [opscode example](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_ruby_block.html) - under "Stash a file in a data bag")

In the Chef output, I can see my recipe file being loaded:

```
[2013-09-18T13:19:45+00:00] DEBUG: Loading Recipe chef-magento::copy_ssl_certificates via include_recipe
```

and, lower down, I can see the directory being created:

```
[2013-09-18T13:22:40+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/etc/httpd/ssl] action create (apache2::default line 138)
[2013-09-18T13:22:40+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/httpd/ssl] created directory /etc/httpd/ssl
[2013-09-18T13:22:40+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/httpd/ssl] owner changed to 0
[2013-09-18T13:22:40+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/httpd/ssl] group changed to 0
[2013-09-18T13:22:40+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/httpd/ssl] mode changed to 755
[2013-09-18T13:22:40+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/etc/httpd/conf.d] action create (apache2::default line 145)
```

but at no point does it run my code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change the action `:nothing` to `:run` ..

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `subscribes :create, "directory[/etc/httpd/ssl]"` ?

Comment: Yes I tried that first. I switched to the `resources()` syntax when that didn't work, as it seemed more explicit.

Comment: this should be comment, not an answer.